# Looking for a modifiable signature!

Tags: encryption, rsa, signature, integrity, bls-signature

I am a graduate student and have encountered some problems in my research. When I generate a signature on the data block of the file, and the signature is composed of the user's private key, the data block, and the block index. Is there any signature algorithm that can modify the block index value after the original signature is generated to obtain the user's signature without changing the other parts.

Comment: If you need to modify it, then why sign it? And who will need to modify it?

Comment: This is in the context of data integrity, users upload data and related data tags to the cloud for storage, in order to ensure that their data will not be destroyed, so to regularly audit, usually by a third party to verify the integrity of the data. Because the third party is untrusted, the mapping between the file and its index number given by the user is wrong (if the third party knows the correct mapping, it can infer the private information of the file), but the incorrect mapping will cause the verification of the third party to fail as usual.

Comment: Because the validation process third party will use the wrong index number to calculate. So I want the user to create the original tag, and then let the cloud modify the tag (i.e., the signature of the file) based on the incorrect file index, so that the third party can be verified without any problems, and the file privacy is protected.

Comment: Letting untrusted third party verify the files already give them too much information about the users. Also: https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1566

Comment: The third party verifies the integrity of the data based on the proof sent by the cloud, and he cannot get the contents of the file.

Comment: Without further information it's unclear why you would not simply *not* sign the index. But you may want to look into the concept of Sanitizable Signatures.

Comment: Thank you very much! From the abstract it seems to fit my idea, I will read the paper!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works for you: hash the index + random value as well as the data, giving you two hashes. Then sign a structure containing those hashes.

Now give the signature & the data and the signature to the untrusted auditor. They can verify the structure and therefore the hash over the data, but as they don't know either the index or the random they won't be able to get any information about that.

Of course the random value needs to be 128-256 bits and the random generator & hash algorithm do need to be cryptographically secure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My idea is not that the index number itself cannot be known by the auditor. To be more specific, a certain data is considered special. This will make the document indistinguishable from a regular document.

Comment: If the user generates a signature based on two indexes separately, it will waste a lot of computing resources, so I want the cloud to modify the index part in the signature generated by the user to meet the challenge of the auditor, which will not modify the data itself.